# Query Custom User Class Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, parse-platform

I'm trying to query three columns that I created in my user class with parse. I successfully saved them to the user class. But I'm having difficulty query these three columns onto a label. I really don't know where to start with the query, I want it to be user specific of course, so user A gets his name, bio, gender, ect. And name is the user's full name, **not** their username.

This is my code to save the objects:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    PFUser *profile = [PFUser currentUser];
    [profile setObject:_name.text forKey:@"Name"];
    [profile setObject:_bio.text forKey:@"Bio"];
    NSString *var = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MyKey"];
    [profile setObject:var forKey:@"Gender"];
    [profile saveInBackground];
}
```

For the query I really don't know, this is where I need help. So if you have any suggestions I would appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: Are you wanting to find just the current user, or a list of users? If a list, what filters are you wanting (there's a limit to how many you can get back at once)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 PFQuery * query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ClassName"];
    [query whereKey:@"Name" equalTo:@"XYZ"];


    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        // objects : PFObjects
        // you can filter out the data you want and print into lable
    }];
```

Comment: I saved my objects in the user class, I'm having difficulty querying them like this. In one user row I want to retrieve a object and print it onto a label.

Comment: instead of [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ClassName"]; try [PFUser query];

Comment: @Subash Thanks for that, the "_User" name may change in the future.